# How to upload image from a dynamically Generated Form in CodeIgniter using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to upload an image to a local folder using jquery ajax. The complex part is i have the forms which are generated dynamically, and to those forms and fields i am giving the id to it so as to show which form is submitted as shown below. I am using following code but the image is not uploaded.

> View: Upload_View.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendVideoData(frm_id)
    {    
        var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("post_video_"+frm_id));
        // make the AJAX request
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"dashboard/do_upload",
            data: data+'&form_id='+frm_id,
            mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("data"+data);
            },            
        });        
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form name="post_video" id="post_video_<?=$row1['id']?>" method="post" onsubmit="return sendVideoData(<?=$row1['id']?>)">           
    <input type="file" name="save_movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" id="movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" /> 
    <input name="type_lecture_id" class="get_lecture_id" id="get_lecture_id_<?=$row1['id']?>" value="<?=$row1['id']?>" type="hidden"/>
    <input type="button" class="postbtn" id="submit_movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" value="Upload Video File"/>
</form>
```

> Controller:

```
$formid=$_POST['form_id']; 

$filename='save_movie_'.$formid;
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES[$filename]["name"]);
$extension = $path_parts['extension'];
$Random_file_name=$filename.".".$extension;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$filename]['tmp_name'], "http://localhost/dummy/uploads/".$Random_file_name);
```

save_movie_ this is the id of the file control and $formid shows from which form and which field we have to take data, but because i am new to Codeigniter i don't know from how to upload it. One thing more i want to display progress bar also to display the progress of image upload.Please reply. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You must have to modify your jQuery ajax function in the following way

```
   var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("post_video_"+frm_id)[0]);
   jQuery("#progressbar").show(); // add your prgress bar here like this
   jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"dashboard/do_upload",
        data: data+'&form_id='+frm_id,
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("data"+data);
            jQuery("#progressbar").hide(); //hide your loader like this
        },            
    });        
    return false;
```

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks Shyam, but main problem is i have different form generated and i have to get the field from which the user is uploading file for eg. form_id='frm_id' is the form id how can i fetch it on the do_upload controller function and upload image from it.

Comment: As u can see above in my question the dynamic id of the form and fields.How can i upload image or other files.

Comment: yes. you can use onclick event of javascript in your input submit button . e.g.    <input type="button" class="postbtn"  onclick="sendVideoData(<?=$row1['id']?>)" id="submit_movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" value="Upload Video File"/>. Hope this will work. Thank you. @user3653474

Comment: that i am doing i am passing id to my function from this sendVideoData(<?=$row1['id']?>) code, and i have passed that  frm_id also to controller but i have problem in how to upload it. Can u please let me know how can i upload it to my local folder .

Comment: Because i have searched every where but i did'nt find any solution regarding image upload using forms and fields which are dynamically generated.

Comment: are you printing print_r($_FILES[$filename]); like this in controller .Is it printing array for image? and also check your firefox console that file is passing or not. @user3653474

Comment: In the ajax i can get the value i.e. 47 but i have to transfer it to controller and concatenate to the file type name such as save_movie_.id.

Comment: try by coding removing  mimeType:"multipart/form-data", from script because I have never used  mimeType:"multipart/form-data", in any of image or fileupload and then try print_r($_FILES); before passing to controller try alert(data); is this contain data? @user3653474

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92843/discussion-between-shyam-and-user3653474).